# get attribute with getattr from a object in python

Tags: python, object, error-handling, attributes

I have an object p ([liblas.point.Point](http://www.liblas.org/tutorial/python.html)) with several attributes

```
pattr = {
    "r": 'return_number',
    "n": 'number_of_returns',
    "s": 'get_point_source_id()',
    "e": 'flightline_edge',
    "c": 'classification',
    "a": 'scan_angle',
}

mylist = ["r", "n", "e", "c", "a"]

for letter in mylist:
    print getattr(p, pattr[letter])

1
3
0
1
-23
```

I have a problem with  `get_point_source_id()` where

```
p.get_point_source_id()
20
```

but when i use getattr i got this message

```
getattr(p, pattr["s"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2721, in run_code
    exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns
  File "<ipython-input-81-bbad74aa3829>", line 1, in <module>
    getattr(p, pattr["s"])
AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'get_point_source_id()'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are almost certainly not part of the attribute name. Get rid of them when calling `getattr()`. Then you need to call the method:

```
attr_name = pattr[letter]
if not attr_name.endswith("()"):
  print getattr(p, attr_name)
else:
  print getattr(p, attr_name[:-2])()
```

Comment: if i remove i got: <bound method Point.get_point_source_id of <liblas.point.Point object at 0x0000000108BA2A90> instead of "20"

Comment: Try calling it afterwards. `getattr(p, 'get_point_source_id')()`.

Comment: yes It works Thanks, but i need do understand ho to insert in the loop above